# Compressing Images GUI

Tags: image, user-interface, compression, command-line-interface

Is there an open source GUI for compressing images?

All I've found are CLI's so I'd like to build a simple online UI for compressing images.

What programming language do I have to use for this? I was hoping to use PHP but I have no clue.

Comment: I'm a bit confused; are you asking about writing your own image compression routines? Or is this more about writing a GUI to interface with an existing CLI compression program?

Comment: I'd like to use pngcrush in a web application for compressing images but I don't have a clue on how to implement it.

Comment: That's a bit out of my domain, but it'll baisically boil down to converting user input to a command-line invocation right? Something sort of like this? http://www.r1ch.net/stuff/gif2png/webinterface/pngcrush.cgi

Comment: you can get the source code and/or binaries for pngcrush at http://sourceforge.net/projects/pmt/files/. From there it's up to you how you want to call them, if you're using PHP and the binaries you could try exec() or passthru() or something.

Comment: @alrikai Exactly although I'd like to have a slightly bigger file limit.